# Issue with big border size (not full rectangle)

Tags: css

When i set a big `border-size`

```
border: 1px solid #ced4da;
border-top: 6px solid #ffc107;
```

the yellow top border (the big one 6px) is not a full rectangle

[image]

I dont what this

[image]

I want this

How can i fix this ?

[image]

Comment: post you full code. also the question is not understood

Comment: It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. Also, what is a "big `border-size`"? 100px 1000px? 10000px? And what do you mean by "not uniform"? For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ObsidianAge i add some info

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar i update my question

Comment: @Youssef :claps: for the update. But the question is still a mystery.

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar Look now ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want if you add extra HTML elements, but `box-shadow` will allow you to use pure CSS.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #ced4da;
  border-top: 6px solid #ffc107;
}

.square-top-fix {
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0px -6px #ffc107;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Original version
</div>
<div class="square-top-fix">
  Fixed version
</div>
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution, I like it!

Comment: Yeah it's a good solution unless i have already a box-shadow in my div but i will opt for this solution

Comment: @Youssef you can add multiple box-shadows to any element. Just put a comma between each shadow definition:

box-shadow: 0px -6px #ffc107, 0px 6px #ffc107, -6px 0px #ffc107, 0px 6px #ffc107;

Answer (score 1):

Borders in css will always have that sloped edge if you also have side borders, like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-top: 10px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<div />
```

If you want the top 'border' to be a pure rectangle, you could fake it like this:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid red;
 }
 
#div2 {
  /* Negative margin will move this div into the border */
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  /* width = div width + border width * 2 */
  width: 120px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks man for help it's a good solution but if i have some padding in div1 and with in % things gets complicated

Comment: Yea I think @actual-size solution is nicer, however, you could always use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to deal with % widths and such.